# How to disable the "go to definition" on pressing CTRL key in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I usually use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+click combination to select one word, but in Visual Studio 2017 (15.4) when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> the word is turned into a hyperlink that goes to its definition, I want to disable it:

[image]

Comment: Note the [Enable mouse click](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/75688/vs-2017-preview-153-enable-mouse-click-to-perform.html) checkbox.  Turn it off and try again.

Comment: If it's answer I would upvote & accept.. thanks

Comment: So many annoying/counter-productive features, set ON by default, started to pop up with each major VS release. A lot of people cannot adopt it for good. I would be happy to turn off once and forget, unfortunately, all settings are restored whenever an update takes place. Brr..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Tools->Options->Text Editor->General

Uncheck `Enable mouse click to perform Go to definition`

It will work

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This was enabled by default on a fresh install on Visual Studio 2022 Professional - God knows why. 

For other people searching: Pressing CTRL in javascript brought up "Cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret"

Answer (score 1):

This setting has no effect when the "Ctrl+Click Go To Definition" Extension from Microsoft Marketplace is installed.  The setting specified on the extension documentation page wasn't visible in the Options, Productivity Power Tools, Other Extensions, and hence, masked the real problem.  Uninstalling the extension allows reverting to classic Ctrl+Click select behavior.